# Convert date string YYYY-MM-DD to YYYYMM in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

Is there a way in pandas to convert my column date which has the following format '1997-01-31' to '199701', without including any information about the day?

I tried solution of the following form:

`df['DATE'] = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%m'))`

but I obtain this error : 'ValueError: time data '1997-01-31' does not match format '%Y%m''

Probably the reason is that I am not including the day in the format. Is there a way better to pass from YYYY-MM_DD format to YYYYMM in pandas?

Comment: What is the `dtype` of the`'DATE'` column? Is it `datetime` or `str`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might not need to go through the `datetime` conversion if the data are sufficiently clean (no incorrect strings like `'foo'` or `'001231'`):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1997-01-31', '1997-03-31', '1997-12-18']})

df['date'] = [''.join(x.split('-')[0:2]) for x in df.date]
#     date
#0  199701
#1  199703
#2  199712
```

Or if you have `null` values:

```
df['date'] = df.date.str.replace('-', '').str[0:6]
```

Comment: What then if I need to get back to the original format? Is there a similar quick way?

Answer (score 14):

One way is to convert the date to date time and then use strftime. Just a note that you do lose the datetime functionality of the date

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['1997-01-31' ]})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m')


    date
0   199701
```